# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How to debug the error that I've encountered right now., I am creating an app which is can locate the current location with google map then i've got some tutorial on how to do it., but the errors came up.

```
*Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

 <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Inverse" 
  parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse"/>

*Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.`

 <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" 
  parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored"/>
```

they are belong in 
`*C:\Users\rifrancisco\Desktop\androidprojects\MapsII\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml`

i'm using Android Studio 1.3 with the SDK Platforms up to 5.x(MNC) and all the SDK tools were installed

how can I resolve this ? i've also try to change the version to v23 in project structure but still the same.. here are my codes

MyActivity

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is     not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play          services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
 v* A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)     getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,     0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));

        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager;
        locationManager = (LocationManager)     getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // set map type
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        // Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Show the current location in Google Map
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,     longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located"));
    }
```

and here is the codes under values-v23.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/googleplex-android/mnc-        supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-        v23/styles_base_text.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Inverse"     parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse"/>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/googleplex-android/mnc-    supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-    v23/themes_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light"     parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?    android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
        <!-- We can use the platform styles on v23+ -->
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">?    android:attr/actionMenuTextAppearance</item>

        <item     name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light"     parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
        <!-- We can use the platform styles on v23+ -->
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">?android:attr/actionMenuTextAppearance</item>

        <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
    </style>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/googleplex-android/mnc-    supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-    v23/styles_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"     parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your `build.gradle` file. Most probably your `targetSdkVersion` is below `23`. Change it according to your level API.

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
...
}
```

Comment: where can i see the bulid.graddle file ?

Comment: <project_root>/app/build.gradle

Comment: It's working now.. thank you sir Llya .. God Bless :)

Comment: If its working accept it as the answer.